# SCDF server failing to start with the k8s version 1.20

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We recently upgraded to k8s version 1.20.9 and not sure if that is the root cause but SCDF server pod fails to come up with the error below.

I usually deploy scdf server using kubectl based deployment.

Anyone has any idea ? Attached error below.

> 2022-01-05 05:08:56.207  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Starting ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"] 2022-01-05 05:08:56.300  WARN 1 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
> start embedded Tomcat server 2022-01-05 05:08:56.798  INFO 1 --- [
> main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2022-01-05
> 05:08:56.893  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> initiated... 2022-01-05 05:08:57.194  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> completed. 2022-01-05 05:08:57.197  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Pausing ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"] 2022-01-05 05:08:57.197  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2022-01-05 05:08:57.292  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Stopping ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"] 2022-01-05 05:08:57.293  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Destroying ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"] 2022-01-05 05:08:57.793 ERROR 1 --- [           main]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
> start embedded Tomcat server Caused by:
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
> start embedded Tomcat server Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> standardService.connector.startFailed Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

What stands out in the trace is `SocketException: permission denied` It is likely due to some security configuration change in the upgrade  affecting the TCP layer. I would start with your security configuration. Keep us posted.